# Is there an easy way to time pytorch code running in GPU?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

Are there any easy ways to time pytorch code (python) while running in GPU ( not in CPU)? I can simply use the `time` module builtin in python to time code in CPU. However are there any easy way to use functions to time code for GPU? Thanks.